# Kill process started with System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("FileName")

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am trying to create an app that will perform actions on specific times (much like the Windows Task Scheduler). I am currently using Process.Start() to launch the file (or exe) required by the task.

I am initiating a process by calling a file (an .mp3) and the process starts WMP (since it is the default application).  So far so good. Now I want to kill that process. I know that it is normal behavior for the Process.Start(string, string) to return nothing (null in C#) in this case.

So I am asking how can I close WMP when I called it through Process.Start(string, string)??

Edit:

Please note that I am not opening WMP directly with Process.Start() and this is the line with which I run the process:

> VB: Me._procs.Add(Process.Start(Me._procInfo))

C#: this._procs.Add(Process.Start(this._procInfo))

_procInfo is a ProcessStartInfo instance. _procInfo.FileName is "C:\route\myFile.mp3". That is why WMP opens. In any case, all of the Start() methods, except for the instance-one which returns a boolean, return nothing (null in C#), because WMP is not the process that was directly created (please note that WMP is run and the song does play).

Comment: To my knowledge, `Process.Start` will only return `null` if no process was actually started, e.g. an existing process was reused to load the document (in your case, an mp3 file). Do you really want to be killing a process your code didn't actually start?

Comment: @Ani - the static Start calls all return Process but the member function returns bool

Comment: @Steve Townsend: Right, but I believe the OP is talking about the static method. If a reference to a non-null `Process` object were already available, then the problem wouldn't exist.

Comment: @0xA3, my bad :), confused between the static and member functions

Comment: This is the overload I'm using: Process.Start(Me._procInfo). That opens WMP but returns nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't do it this way.

It's not clear whether the intent of your program is 'Always launch with Windows Media Player' or 'Launch with the registered MP3 player', which might be, say, iTunes.

If you need WMP, use Process.Start with the full path to windows media player.

If you need the registed MP3 player, you can find out the correct exe using [the code shown here](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/paytonbyrd/how-to-use-findexecutable-from-c-3324). Again, start the process with this exe path, passing the MP3 as a parameter.

Answer (score 22):

Process.Start(string,string) returns you a Process resource that you can use to further control the new process.

```
Process newProcess = Process.Start("param1", "param2");
if (newProcess != null && !newProcess.HasExited)
  newProcess.Kill();
```

The same structure works if you use `Process.Start(string)`, or any other static Process.Start overload.

`Process.Start()` is a member function and associates a new or reused `Process` with the `Process` component identified by this.  Behaviour of this method depends on the properties of the Process identified by `this`.

Comment: Best answer. One gotcha: the user may have closed the app that was launched from `Process.Start`, in which case the handle won't be null but it'll blow up if you call `Kill()`. Wrap the kill in a try/catch and you'll be safe.

Answer (score 5):

Two ways:

1-

```
Process customProc = Process.Start("ExecutablePath", "Argument(s)");  
customProc.Kill()
```

2-

```
Dim pProcess() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName")  
For Each p As Process In pProcess
p.Kill()
Next
```

Comment: The thing about this is that since I am not the one starting the program (I am just calling the file and windows is handling the program it should open with) Process.Start returns nothing (null for C#).

Answer (score 3):

If you are letting the registered windows program to open the file, rather than picking the program you want. Then I advise you do not kill the process.

The reason for this is what say your program does use the default application, but that application is already in use, and contains unsaved data. A user would not be happy for your program to overtake there application with the new file and then kill off the process that was already in use by the user for another purpose. Sure, it might not be in use but you must consider the worst case.

As such, I recommend what has been suggested. use Process.Start() with the full path to the program to be used and the file to be opened.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to open .txt file and the process of my text editor was returned, also I tried .mp3 by WMP and it returned null. So it depends on the application. Do you need to run you mp3 only with WMP? If not, you definitely can create the application which will return the Process object.

Answer (score 1):

`proc = Process.Start(filename)` should work, but like you say, it returns null instead of a process.

That seems to be inherent to Windows Media Player. Other applications return the process. You can get Windows Media Player's process by specifying the application in the start method.

```
proc = Process.Start("C:\Program Files\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe", filename)
```

Then you can kill it normally.

```
proc.Kill()
```

You will probably need to get the location of the application assiciated with .mp3 files from the registry.