# How do I run a C program as a thread from a C# System Tray Application?

Tags: c#, c, windows, multithreading, system-tray

I have a C console application which used to be run in the foreground in a `CMD` terminal in `Windows` and take user keystroke inputs. However it now needs to be moved to the background and requires no user input.

I have created a system tray, which is implemented correctly with a right click exit and right click about. And have a terminal program which does the functionality.

Rather than rewritting the program again I would like to be able to create a thread which calls the functions from my existing program which are do not require the terminal.

Just to stress the point the console interactive aspects have been removed from the code as have the applications response to keystrokes etc. Hopefully this clarifies things slightly.

**Question:** Is this possible? And how would I be able to implement this?

(I am generally not a PC programmer using more embedded C so .NET is quite foreign to me. Any help is greatly appreciated)

Comment: A *C program* is far too vague. I'm guessing you mean a *console application written in C*, in which case the answer is *no*, a console application cannot be run as a tray application without modifications; it would have to at least have a window handle and a message loop in order to receive notifications, which console applications don't have.

Comment: not enough details to answer.... but it is possible for your .NET program to launch your console application in the background.

Comment: @Keith: That's not a tray application, though, which is what the question asks.

Comment: a tray application can launch the process

Comment: Luke, does your C program expect any king of keystroke, user input?

Comment: Let me reword it to be more clear. Apologies.

Comment: @rodrigogq it does not expect any kind of user input any more

Comment: I think in order to do this, the functions in your C program must be exported using something like `_declspec(dllexport)`

Comment: Yep, the best way to go is almost certainly to rebuild your C program as a DLL which exports one or more functions.  I'm fairly sure you can call arbitrary DLLs from C#, though I'm not familiar with the method.

Comment: If he want to just start and exit the process, I don't see why he needs to go so far.. Just start.. and exit when user asks to exit. Am I missing something here? The about box would´t have to ask for terminal version or something like. They are separated stuff.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - He wouldn't even need to rebuild it as a DLL. You can still export functions in an EXE file. But it does make more sense as a DLL

Comment: @rodrigogq - From his question, he states "I would like to be able to create a thread which calls the functions from my existing program".

Comment: @icemanind thanks. Then I removed my answer. Anyway, exporting is a good option.

Comment: @rodrigogq It does seem I will rebuild as a DLL. Rodrigogq you mentioned that I may be able to just start and exit the process, how would I syntactically be able to do this as this sounds to me like the simplest option? Or is this not a good idea?

Comment: @icemanind Hi I will probably export to DLL. However is there any reason not to just be able to  start and exit the process. I did say I was looking to call my functions from a thread, however if it is possible to just start the C application (without opening the terminal) in the background, and close it with the system application I can't see why I wouldn't do it this way... Thanks

Comment: @Luke I undeleted my answer for reference. If you are not calling anything, just running, try that.

Comment: @rodrigogq - Sorry man. I might have given you bad advice. It just  sounded, from his question, that he wanted to be able to call functions from the C program. If your answer works for him, its definitely simpler and you deserve the answer credit. I upvoted your answer, in any case.

Comment: @icemanind never mind! I learned from your code also! :)

Comment: icemanind and rodrigogq have both put forward good answers that appear they will be solutions to my problem. I will update on Monday and say which option I went with and how easy they were to implement.

Comment: Encase any one was interested: I implemented both rodrigogq and icemanind solutions; -rodrigogq solution to use Process.Start was incredibly easy to implement (a helpful related link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847330/kill-process-started-with-system-diagnostic-process-startfilename) -was limited when it comes to closing the process correctly however. -icemanind solution was harder to implement,had advantages in terms of control (e.g. needed if writing to file) I used rodrigogq solution in this instance but there is definitely similar situations using DLL is more appropriate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already posted, you could use the `Process.Start` from your C# application tray.

```
    // Uses the ProcessStartInfo class to start new processes, 
    // both in a minimized mode. 
    void OpenWithStartInfo()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
        startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

        Process.Start(startInfo);

        startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

        Process.Start(startInfo);
    }
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx

You could try launching it on a hidden state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle(v=vs.110).aspx

Some programmers are telling to be careful. If any input is expected, then probably your process might halt. make sure nothing really *stops* your program.

You could try to start a `cmd` command with `Process.Start` also, but I would say it is just too much. This would start another process without your C# tray application control:

```
 Process.Start("start /min cmd /c mycommand");
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure that he wants to call his executable. I'm thinking he might want to call a specific function or specific functions that is compiled into his executable.

Comment: @rodrigogq I think a better solution for my problem is to create a thread that calls DLL functions. Though your answer I might be able to use for a slightly different application I am also needing to automate. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but if you are asking if you can call functions from your C program from a C# application, then you can. So long as you have the source code to your C program. In order for functions in C to be available to a C# program, they must be exported. I will show you an example:

MyAddDll.h

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a, int b);
}
```

Whats important here is that your function is wrapped in an `extern "C"` block. Basically, this tells the compiler not to mangle the name of your function. The other important piece is `__declspec(dllexport)`. This tells the compiler that you want to export this function so it can be called from another program (like your C# program).

MyAddDll.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "MyAddDll.h"

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int Add(int a, int b)
    {
        return (a + b);
    }
}
```

Again, your code gets wrapped in an `extern "C"` block and you need to add `__declspec(dllexport)` to the function. Now you can compile this either into a DLL file or an EXE file. Now to call it from C#, its pretty straight forward:

MyProgram.cs

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("c:\\PathToMyDllOrExeFile\\MyAddDll.dll")]
    public static extern int Add(int val1, int val2);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int val1 = 12;
        int val2 = 4;
        Console.WriteLine("{0} + {1} = {2}", val1, val2, Add(val1, val2));
    }
}
```

That's all there is!

One "gotcha" though is make sure your C program and your C# program are both compiled as either 32-bit or 64-bit. You can't compile your C program as 64-bit and your C# program as 32-bit. They must both be using the same bit length.

Comment: Hi thanks that is very helpful. If I have multiple C files would they all need to be wrapped in the DLL or if I wrap the main as a DLL can it call the other C files?

Comment: @Luke - Any C files that contain functions you want to be able to call in C# need to be wrapped

Comment: Thank you. This should be helpful in implementing the change. Cheers

Comment: @Luke - One other thing. I made the assumption that your C program was compiled using Microsoft's Visual Studio. If this is not correct, let me know and I'll update my answer. `__declspec(dllexport)` only exists in Microsoft's compiler. For any other compiler, we would have to make an export.def file.

Comment: I am using the latest free version of Microsoft Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You could start your C program from .NET code via System.Diagnostics.Process. It will be run in a separate process.

You can kill the process from .NET code as well

Comment: The question asks about a *system tray application*, which is not the same as a console application launched via `Process`.